# AWS AppSync Client SDK

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-appsync

Is there any way to send the mutation, query using AWS Java SDK? I need to use it using IAM Role

```
Default authorization mode = AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)
```

Also, there is no function to make a query and send it

```
    AWSAppSync awsAppSync = AWSAppSyncClient.builder().build();
```

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/amazon-archives/aws-mobile-appsync-events-starter-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/demo/appsync/AddEventActivity.java#L90) of use to you?

Comment: nnope not an android, I am spring boot